# I want to use string formatting to limit decimals and right align numbers. But I don't know how

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, string-interpolation

I apologize to those who find it difficult to answer due to my awkward sentences.

```
//Numbers are entered using the keyboard
double num1 = 10.234256; 
double num2 = 593.242523333;
double num3 = -32423.412929333425;

Console.WriteLine($"{num1:f3, 25}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num2:f3, 25}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num3:f3, 25}");
```

I wrote the code like above. I thought the decimal point would be limited and the numbers would be aligned 25 spaces to the right, but that didn't happen. I need to use string interpolation, and also don't want to use a rounding function.

I tried using these codes String.Format, {0:f3, 25} to solve this problem. But all failed.

Without using System.Linq, please use the code {0:f3} to limit the decimal point to 3 digits and tell me how to right or left align the number.

Comment: how about `num1.ToString("f3").PadRight(25)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment component should precede the format string component:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{num1,25:f3}");
```

Here is the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-item-syntax):

```
{index[,alignment][:formatString]}
```